# How do I use Greenhopper to manage developers across multiple projects?

Tags: project-management, jira, agile, jira-plugin, jira-agile

We are currently using Jira 5.1.6 with GreenHopper 6.0.5. We have a lot of projects, probably about a dozen total but only a few that are actively worked on at a time, with the rest being there for occasional bugfixes or other tasks. The 4–5 developers in our company are likely to be working on a couple projects at once (some working on just one, some working on maintenance on several, and it somewhat varying who's working on what depending on the business priorities).

So, GreenHopper seems set up from a very project-centric view. I can set up a Rapid Scrum Board for a project, and make Sprints within it of work to do for that project. This can give the business a good view of work into that project. Potentially, one can also make a Board for all of the projects (since GreenHopper 6 added that), and make a kind of "global sprint" across everything. If we were to have this kind of global sprint, all of the project owners would need to work at once on figuring out what should get done over the next couple weeks, which might be workable, but seems a bit tricky and would require a lot of coordination.

What I think we want is some kind of "resource view" or something, so that project owners could set up their tasks in their sprints, but there's some sort of view for each developer to tell them what task they should be working on next no matter which project's sprint it's in, and some way for our manager to allocate our time across the projects. So, I might be scheduled to work, for example, 20 hours a week on project A, 10 on project B, and 10 on maintenance of other projects, and then project owners making sprints could see how much time they had allocated, and I as a developer would see some kind of unified view of my upcoming tasks, so that I would know what I should be working on next and what's coming soon. I don't know if that description is exactly what we want, but I think we want something along those lines, and it seems like we can't be the only place that wants some sort of project-based view as well as a resource-based view.

The thoughts I've had of how we might approach this from my exploration of GreenHopper so far are:

1. Create those "global" sprints I mentioned, and work as a department at the beginning of each sprint to try to schedule what we'll all be doing. Projects can get a look at their particular piece of the sprint using a Quick Filter or somesuch, and we just have to deal with coordinating those sprints.
2. Use the "Parallel Sprints" feature on an all-projects Board, and have each developer create their own sprints of the tasks they have coming up. This helps with getting a resource-based view, but is probably tough for projects to figure out status of things, and definitely feels like squeezing GreenHopper into a space that it really doesn't want to go.
3. Create a board for each project of the things to be coming up for each project, so each project gets its own Sprints and we get the project-based view of things, and just have each developer track themselves which projects' sprints they should be getting tasks from. Basically, just GreenHopper isn't the tool for a resource-based view, so don't even bother, and trust our developers and our manager to look across all these projects for what tasks to work from rather than trying to do it all in one place.

None of those seem great, though I'm sure we could make do with any of them. But I keep on coming back to that it doesn't feel like we're doing something bizarre or unique to us, and we would have thought that since Jira/GreenHopper was an industry-standard agile tool that it'd be easier to use it for what we're trying to do. Are we doing something crazy? I think we'd be fine with changing our process to use standard practices if there's a standard way of doing Agile across multiple projects out there. Is there some GreenHopper setting or report or something somewhere I've missed? Is there some other Jira plugin that we should be using instead of or in addition to GreenHopper? Do other teams out there use one of the above approaches and can give advice on whether or not it's a good idea?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question in perhaps the more appropriate place, on the Atlassian forum:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/99020/how-do-i-use-greenhopper-to-manage-developers-across-multiple-projects

And I think the answer there from them was very good. I created a board for each project, limited to its project and used for creating that project's sprints, and the developers use an "All Projects" board to see all of the sprints that they're a part of.

Doesn't handle resource allocation wonderfully, as mdoar states, but it does seem to be using the tool the best way that it can be for this for now.

Answer (score 1):

"... seems a bit tricky and would require a lot of coordination." Yup, sounds like project management to me.

I'd create boards for each product that gets released on its own schedule. I'd also create a query to show each user the issues assigned to them sorted by Sprint so they can see what work is on their plate. The issues will be across multiple boards and sprints.

I do wish that GH helped with resource allocation more, including totaling up the time allocated in the filter in the previous paragraph. At the moment I end up exporting the results of the filter to Excel and using that to sum up totals by resource.